# How to create single endpoint for authenticated or non-authenticated User in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-authentication

I need a single endpoint where I can check if User authenticated then can return some user-related data else(if not-authenticated) some basic information that I want.

I tried by checking user having a token or not in the api.php file. but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The example below is basically generated by following the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication).

```
//file: ./routes/web.php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Route::get('profile', function () {

  if (Auth::check()) {
    return Auth::user();
  } else {
    return ['foo' => 'bar'];
  }

});
```

**Have in mind that this is extremely simplified example.**

In a real world case use probably you would have a [route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#basic-routing) pointing to a controller method where you can auto-inject the `Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager`. 
Also you wouldn't be returning the whole user object, but rather [transforming the response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources) to your needs.